# Google Analytics - Match URLs on Unique Number in Content Drilldown Using RegEx?

Tags: regex, google-analytics, analytics, zendesk

I am trying to track pageviews on Google Analytics for knowledge base articles (on Zendesk).
Each article has a unique number. However, the title of the page is sometimes appended to the URL, and GA tracks this as a separate page. If the title of the article changes, it generates a new URL.

For example, these would all be the same article, so I want to see a single pageviews count, but GA would show as 3 separate stats

```
/hc/en-us/articles/360039413394
/hc/en-us/articles/360039413394-How-To-Make-A-Sandwich
/hc/en-us/articles/360039413394-How-To-Make-A-Turkey-Sandwich
```

I want GA to roll up the articles matching on the unique number, and ignoring everything after that. Is there a built-in way to do this? Is there a way to do this with Regex? Where would I add the Regex for the Content Drilldown page? Help!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Analytics cannot know in an integrated way which part of the URL interests you or which distinguishes one page from another.

What you should do is understand when in your system the page title is appended to the URL and avoid it.

For future data you can try to clean the data with a regex before it arrives in Analytics, for example with GTM, but this could compromise the other URL cases that need to be handled differently.

In general, if in the Analytics reports you filter the URLs for an identifier, for example `360039413394`, in the **first** row of the report you can see the aggregated values of all the URLs that contain that *string*. So if you need to verify a particular product page you can use this workaround when viewing data.